# MySQL - SELECT multiple row in one table with connected id

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like this in mySQL

```
id_file    | file_name     | id_parent
1          | a             | null
2          | b             | null
3          | a_new         | 1
4          | a_new_new     | 3
5          | c             | null
6          | b_new         | 2
```

I want to get every row which have 'connectivity' with others row.

I mean when i want to select id_file = 4, i can get the id_file = 3 and id_file = 1 too... (Because id_file 4 **have parent in** id_file 3 and id_file 3 **have parent in** id_file 1)

So when i select id_file = 4, the result will be like this

```
id_file    | file_name     | id_parent
1          | a             | null
3          | a_new         | 1
4          | a_new_new     | 3
```

My question is, what is the query to get multiple row which have connectivity with other row (like a asked above)?

Comment: It's not easy. [This](https://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/) might be relevant.

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from https://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/

```
SELECT T2.id_file, T2.file_name,T2.id_parent
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := id_parent FROM tablename WHERE id_file= _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 4, @l := 0) vars,
        tablename m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN tablename T2
ON T1._id = T2.id_file
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC;
```

Comment: After a while, finally i understand your answer. And it solve my problem. Thanks